# C++ wrapper class, leave base uninitialized when using specific constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization

Trying to create a wrapper class, somewhat like `std::optional`, but using inheritance to allow seamless conversion to the wrapped class. It only has to work for classes, simple values are handled by a different specialization. It would be used as way to return a value or indicate it's not possible to do so. The wrapper would store some information useful in further flow control (not shown in example).

A simple-as-possible example of the wrapper (would be a template of course) and how it would(n't) be used:

```
struct base { // can be any class type
    base(int& i1, int& i2) : a{i1}, b{i2} {
        ++counter;
    }

    int& a;
    int& b;

    static inline int counter {0};
};

class wrapper : public base { // would be template in normal use
private:

public:
    bool valid {true};

    using base::base; // called for var2

    wrapper() : valid{false} {} // called for var1, should leave base uninitialized
};

auto do_stuff(base b) { return b.a * b.b; }

int main() {
    int i = 1, j = 2;

    wrapper var1;

    if (var1.valid) {
        do_stuff(var1); // won't be called
    }

    wrapper var2(i, j);

    if (var2.valid) {
        do_stuff(var2); // will be called
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KTT1ob9hc

A solution using a dummy initialization of the base class might still produce unwanted side-effects so that's pretty much out of the question.

I know, it feels like fitting a square peg in a round hole, but at the same time it's a good learning experience. Is there a way to be able to use inheritance (as with `var2`) but also leave the base class uninitialized when another constructor is used?

Comment: It's not possible to have uninitialised class object and it's not possible to not have base class object in derived class object.

Comment: No, you can never leave a base class uninitialized; one of its constructor will always be applied. You can provide a constructor that does nothing, but not for this class: references always have to refer to something, so every constructor for the base has to initialize the two references.

Comment: overusing inheritance creates more issues than inheritance can ever solve. When I read the start of the question about a wrapper I would not have expected to see `class wrapper : public base`. A class deriving from `base` is not really a wrapper of `base`

Comment: eg `struct wrapper { std::unique_ptr<base> b; }` grants you complete control of when and where the `base` object is constructed (and initialized)

Comment: This cannot be done in C++, C++ does not work this way. In C++ all base classes must be constructed before the derived class can be constructed. This is fundamental to C++.

Comment: When you want to have a reference member variable in a class, it's almost always better to have that be implemented using a pointer member variable.  The design of `base` will make it extraordinarily easy to have dangling references.  (But even if they were non-owning pointers, it would still be extraordinarily easy to wind up with dangling pointers.)